# Ethernet device requesting data using RESTful API (JSON) and sending string to defined IP?

Tags: json, rest, ethernet

Would appreciate any tips/help.

I have a security system that uses a controller and a video monitoring software, both of which are connected to a LAN (direct ethernet from controller to a POE switch and monitoring software also on same network).

The problem I have is that the security controller can't push strings to an IP address, which is what is required with the video monitoring software.

I need to create a separate device that requests data from the security controller's IP and then takes what the IP address returns (a JSON object) and converts it into a string to send to the video monitoring software's IP address.

Example of the device I need to create:
The device needs to request data from controller 192.168.1.9 address:
http://192.168.1.9/inputs/0.cgi

This will return a JSON object:
{
"description": "Sensor 1",
"type": "NO",
"alarm": false
}

(If the alarm is triggered, "alarm" will be true.)

Then I need to take that JSON object, and convert it into a string (.stringify?)

Then I have to take that string and send it to my video monitoring software's address:

“http:///monitor-mobile/write.fcgi?serverId=1&pin=4&status=1”

This seems uniquely complicated and simple at the same time and I apologize if I left out any information required to solve my problem. Basically, I am wondering if there is a device that I can connect to my network (hard-wired ethernet) that requests data from the security controller and then converts the data (JSON) to a string, and sending it to a different IP (the monitoring service))

Comment: That sounds like a simple development job. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I guess the problem would be that there are several factors I'm not experienced enough to tackle and instead of going down a path that will lead me nowhere I thought maybe someone would be able to direct me towards a solution. Such as what device could be programmed to operate in the fashion I need and exactly how the process would work. I understand it's greedy to ask but I'm stuck.

Comment: You described the process already (query the controller, convert the data, send it to the video monitoring software), there is not much to add. What you need now is to write the piece of software that does exactly this. As for the "device", any computer plugged into your network will do really (you can also use devices like a Raspberry Pi).

Comment: True, and thank you for your time I appreciate it. I created a simple program in python that provides a solution but do you think that this is the right language/program to handle this?

Comment: Yes Python will be fine. This is no "wrong" language to do this.